# Why this $apply in directive is throwing value undefined error

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying write a directive using angular js, in which a button click has to increment a `count` value.

On the click event handler I'm trying to increment the value using the `scope.$apply` construct but it is throwing an `Syntax Error: Token 'undefined' not a primary expression at column NaN of the expression [count++] starting at [count++]` error in the console.

markup

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        <div my-directive >
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.directive('myDirective', function(){
    return {
        scope: {},
        template: '<div>{{count}}</div><input type="button" class="increment" value="Increment" />',
        link: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {
            console.log('link', scope.count)
            iElement.on('click', '.increment', function(){
                console.log('click', scope.count);
                scope.$apply('count++');
            })
        },
        controller: function($scope){
            console.log('controller')
            $scope.count = 0;
        }
    };
});

myApp.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
}]);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3gNus/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing your expression to

```
count = count + 1
```

fixes the problem. Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BinaryMuse/3gNus/1/)

Since Angular doesn't use `eval` to evaluate expressions, you cannot use quite the full range of JavaScript in them; this is one of those exceptions. If you *do* need something a bit more powerful, you can pass a JavaScript function to `$apply` (demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BinaryMuse/3gNus/2/)):

```
scope.$apply(function() {
  scope.count++;
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not just use `ng-click`?

```
<body ng-controller='MainCtrl'>
  <button ng-click="increment()" value="Increment Me!">
  <h1>{{count}}</h1>
</body>
```

And in your JS:

```
function MainCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.count = 0;
  $scope.increment = function() { $scope.count++; };
}
```