# AngularJS: How to monitor an attribute in a directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

In the code below, I want to increase an counter in my directive, and also change the background color. If the counter is even, the background color should be 'red', otherwise 'green'.

However, **the counter works, but the background never changes**. What's wrong with my code?

BTW, two other questions:

1. **the alert dialog does not show, even it is called in the button's ng-click event. Why?**
2. **'counter++' seems not work in ng-click, it must be 'counter = counter + 1', is it correct?**

JavaScript:

```
    function myDirective(){
        return {
            template: '<div>{{count}}</div>',
            replace: false,
            transclude: false,
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {count:'='},
            link: function(scope, el, attrs){

                //-------------  Observe 'count'  ----------------
                attrs.$observe('count', function(newVal, oldVal){
                    var bgColor = newVal % 2 == 0 ? 'red' : 'green';
                    angular.element(el).css('background-color', bgColor);

                });
            } 

        };
    };
    angular.module('app', []).directive('myDirective', myDirective);
```

HTML:

```
    <body data-ng-app='app' data-ng-init="count=1">
        <button ng-click='alert("aa"); count=count+1; '>Increase</button>
        <div my-directive count='count'>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `scope.$watch()` instead of `attrs.$observe()` for isolate scope variables that use the `=` syntax.  (Use $observe with the `@` syntax.)

<kbd>[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/k3gbR/)</kbd>

Inside ng-click(), every function is called on the $scope, so alert() becomes $scope.alert() which is not defined.  (Thank [Dean](http://deansofer.com/posts/view/14/AngularJs-Tips-and-Tricks-UPDATED#scopemethods) for that explanation.)

Angular doesn't use `eval`, so things like `count++` won't work.  See [Brandon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14889761/215945) for more.